# Creating a popup page in dnn 5

Tags: .net, dotnetnuke-5

I have created a user control(.ascx file) in DNN 5 , I want to open that user control as a popup page.
Or in other words ,My asp.net application is using DNN 5, I want to create a popup in my application on the click of a button.
Help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can wrap your control in a div and then use some jQuery to make it popup when you click a a link.

```
    <div id="popupDiv" style="display:none;"> your control here </div>
    <a id="popupLink" href="#"> Popup text </a>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

jQuery("#popupLink").click(function (event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                jQuery("#popupDiv").fadeIn("slow");
            });
</script>
```